# can't send mail with exim4 and php

Tags: php, email, debian, sendmail, exim

i'm using debian & apache.

**if i install sendmail, the php `mail()` function works perfectly.
but else i install exim4, the php `mail()` function does nothing.**

i have changed the php.ini editing the sendmail_path, but i can't send mails (i'm trying sendmail -t -i, sendmail -t and exim4 but any works)

any solution idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you drop in Exim as a replacement for sendmail you should be using `/usr/lib/sendmail` as the path.

Try testing the command you are using from the command line.  This should tell you if you have problems with the command or the problem is between PHP and Exim.   Also check the log file /var/log/exim/maillog to see if there is any indication you are getting the message though to Exim.